# Flyway - Force run repeatable scripts

Tags: flyway

We have a process that has a repeatable script at the end that never changes. So the checksum does not change.
Is there a way to tell Flyway to run it regardless on whether it has run before? Force it to run again.

At the moment I am programmatically alter the file with a unique comment to force it to run. But get tricky when the script is within a Jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like your script should be run as a callback instead, which will give you the desired behavior.

Comment: This is for sure the right answer, checkout the [callback documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks).

Comment: This works thanks. Foolishly ignored the callbacks section in the docs as didn't see the connection.  The documentation states that a script with a callback suffix is run, but I have found that only scripts exactly named as the callback are run. Is this a bug or have I misunderstood?  Also, I think it would be very useful if these where recorded in the schema_version table, as currently no record that they have been run.

Comment: @Stephen I have an alternative solution below if you want to keep an audit trail.

Answer (score 2):

Axels answer is the correct one out of the box.

If you have additional requirements, like keeping a record of their execution in `schema_version`, you could wrap it's execution in [Java Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java) with a [random checksum](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/MigrationChecksumProvider).

```
public class R__MyRepeatable implements JdbcMigration, MigrationChecksumProvider {

    @Override
    public final void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        String scriptLocation = "path/to/maintenance_script.sql";
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(scriptLocation)) {

            if (in == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find file: " + scriptLocation);
            }

            String sql = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

            connection.prepareStatement(sql).execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getChecksum() {
        return ...; // Whatever random / timebased scheme you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi that seems like it would work. Not tried yet as priorities have moved on. Would need to move the repeatable script to its own folder to stop being run with the other migrations (first time). Also, would need one of these for each repeatable script, rather than per folder. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you Name your Script 'afterMigrate.sql' then it is executed every time by flyway after migration. See Flyway Documentation https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks [1](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks)